# Why am I not able to trigger my pipeline upon PR merge into master?

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline which I want to trigger when PR is merged into `master`. I have tried different things, but this did not work. Furthermore, I am neither getting any error nor pipeline is triggering.

I do not want this to be triggered on PR creation. I want this to be triggered when PR is merged into `master`. That is the reason I have not added `pr` in my `yml`.

What am I missing here?

**Approaches:**

- Enabled "Continuous Integration" option [image]
- Following `trigger` syntax per [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#ci-triggers) recommendation

```
trigger:
  batch: True
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  paths:
    include:
    - cosmos
```

- Setting up valid YML file [image]

**Pipeline:**

```
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
  batch: True
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  paths:
    include:
    - cosmos
stages:
  - stage: SOME_PATH_dev
    displayName: SOME_PATH_dev
    jobs:
      - deployment: 'DeployToDev'
        environment: Dev
        cancelTimeoutInMinutes: 1
        pool:
          vmImage: ubuntu-latest
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - checkout: self 
                - task: AzureResourceGroupDeployment@2
                  displayName: Azure Deployment:Create Or Update Resource Group action on SOME_PATH_dev
                  inputs:
                    ConnectedServiceName: SOME_KEY
                    resourceGroupName: SOME_PATH_dev
                    location: West US
                    csmFile: cosmos/deploy.json
                    csmParametersFile: cosmos/parameters-dev.json
                    deploymentName: SOME_PATH.Cosmos.DEV
```

**Repo Structure:**

[image]

**References:**

- ["Configuring the trigger failed, edit and save the pipeline again" with no noticeable error and no further details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68819306/configuring-the-trigger-failed-edit-and-save-the-pipeline-again-with-no-notic)
- [Azure Devops build pipeline: CI triggers not working on PR merge to master when PR set to none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59076697/azure-devops-build-pipeline-ci-triggers-not-working-on-pr-merge-to-master-when)
- https://medium.com/@aksharsri/add-approval-gates-in-azure-devops-yaml-based-pipelines-a06d5b16b7f4
- https://erwinstaal.nl/posts/manual-approval-in-an-azure-devops-yaml-pipeline/

Comment: *That is the reason I have not added pr in my yml.*. Note that the `pr` section in YAML is for **GitHub**, not Azure Pipelines. It wouldn't do anything in Azure Pipelines.

Comment: Does the pipeline work when you trigger it manually? Did you confirm there are no syntax errors?

Comment: @DanielMann Yes for both.

Comment: @DanielMann found the solution. I was updating YML files and expecting trigger. I needed to change any file(s) in `cosmos` folder to trigger the pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

I was changing YML (pipeline) files instead of files inside cosmos folder and expecting trigger.